# Apply text colour and subscript to NSMutableString in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

I am unable to apply both the attributes at the same. Either only color or subscript am able to apply.
Here is my code

```
NSMutableAttributedString * attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"some text"];

[attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                            value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Bold" size:16]
                            range:NSMakeRange(14,1)];
[attributedText addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@-1 range:NSMakeRange(14,1)];

[attributedText addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:85.0/255.0 green:38.0/255.0 blue:152.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] } range:(NSRange){0,6}];
```

Comment: Maybe you have applied wrong range for subscript and color. check Subscript range is `(14,1)` and color range is `(0,6)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
[str addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@-1 range:NSMakeRange(14,1)];

[str setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]}
              range:(NSRange){0,7}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an update for your code workable.

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 200, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:textView];


UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:85.0/255.0 green:38.0/255.0 blue:152.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0];



NSMutableAttributedString * attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"some text"];
    [attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                           value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16]//Lato-Bold, Your font name crahes
                           range:NSMakeRange(8,1)];//x(8) is start index,y(1) is length from start index x(8)


NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color,NSFontAttributeName:font};

[attributedText addAttributes:attrs range:NSMakeRange(0,6)];//start index start from 0, and length start counting from 1
//[attributedText addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@-1 range:NSMakeRange(14,1)];
textView.attributedText = attributedText;
```

OR

You can try with this.

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 200, 44)];

NSString *newsTitle = @"Hello";
NSString *sportTtle = @"World";
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", newsTitle,sportTtle];
textView.text = title;

UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0];

NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color,NSFontAttributeName:font};

NSMutableAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:textView.attributedText];
[attrStr addAttributes:attrs range:[textView.text rangeOfString:sportTtle]];
textView.attributedText = attrStr;
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```